# Dojo Dijit: Why does attr("required", true) fail to set the style "dijitRequired"? or Is there another class which indicates a Dijit is required?

Tags: dojo

As far as I can judge, the CSS-Rule "dijitRequired" is used to mark a required input field. Yet, this style is not set when I apply the "required"-Attribute to a dijit, for example, a date dijit:

The Dijit is built as follows:

```
<input dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox" class="l" id="datumsTestID" name="datumsTest"  tabindex="5" value="2009-01-01" />
```

The Attribute is set with the following Javscript code

```
dijit.byId('datumsTestID').attr('required', true)
```

Am I doing something wrong or is the style "dijitRequired" not intended to be used as I assume?

For my purposes, I patched ValidationTextBox.js to set/unset the class, but is there a cleaner (meaning: more correct) way to set the class or can I style required fields using other attributes?

ValidationTextBox.js, Dojo 1.3, Line 116

```
_setRequiredAttr:function(_12){
    this.required=_12;
    if (_12) dojo.addClass(this.domNode, "dijitRequired"); 
    else dojo.removeClass(this.domNode, "dijitRequired");
    dijit.setWaiState(this.focusNode,"required",_12);
    this._refreshState();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I don't see that code in ValidationTextBox.js or anywhere else.  My _setRequiredAttr() in 1.3 is:

```
_setRequiredAttr: function(/*Boolean*/ value){
this.required = value;
dijit.setWaiState(this.focusNode,"required", value);
this._refreshState();
}
```

Actually I don't see any references to dijitRequired at all, maybe that's something you added to your local copy?

Comment: It is true, the reference to dijitRequired ist in my local copy. I have added it because I needed the Dijit to "look" required when they are set to required.

My issue is also explained in the next post: Would it be possible to add this to the Dojo ValidationTextBox, for me it looks as if my patched version (below) should be the default behaviour. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Setting **dijitRequired** is not enough. **dijit.form.DateTextBox** has its own internal state. Even if **required** attribute is set, this widget display error only when it has been blurred. You can disable this mechanism using such subclass:

```js
dojo.provide("my.DateTextBox");
dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");

dojo.declare("my.DateTextBox", dijit.form.DateTextBox, {
  _setRequiredAttr: function(required){
    this._hasBeenBlurred = true;
    this.inherited(arguments);
  }
});
```